# Adding a Page Editor 'Save and Publish' Button

Tags: .net, sitecore, customization, sitecore6, page-editor

I would like to provide another button beside "Save & Close" button on site Page Editor that will trigger save and publish action once pressed.
I went to core and made a copy of "Save & Close" button that I'm planning to modify.

[image]

I would call this button "Save & Publish", but now I'm kinda curious if I have to modify javascript to include my custom call (let's say `javascript:scSave("myPublish:saveAndPublish")`)

I'm following [this](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/creating-and-running-custom-pipelines-in-sitecore/) article to hook into pipeline and complete the action but not sure if that is proper way.

Any advice?

Comment: You might get a better response on the sitecore developer forum sdn.sitecore.net

Comment: thanks James, I've already cooked up something, but I'll try there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is define a custom command in App_Config/Commands.config:

```
<command name="myPublish:saveAndPublish" 
type="YourNamespace.YourCommand, YourAssembly" />
```

Any custom command needs to subclass Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command and override the method `public override void Execute(CommandContext context)`.

Use your custom command to call the PublishItem command:

```
public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
{
    var publishCommand = new PublishItem();
    publishCommand.Execute(context);
}
```

A few things to look for:

- This has worked for me in Firefox, but not Chrome, where the item is not saved. **scSave** uses a lot of front-end javascript, so this appears to be a bug with Sitecore's Chrome support.
- Strangely, the syntax `scSave("item:publish")` does not work, but calling PublishComand indirectly from a custom command does work.  If anyone figures out why this is, please comment!
- scSave only works when called from a **WebEditButton** (/sitecore/templates/System/WebEdit/WebEdit Button), not a ribbon button ('/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Large Button') or ('/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Small Button').
- The WebEditButton must be located at the top of the ribbon hierarchy ('/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Buttons').  If it is placed on one of the chunks (e.g. "New", "Edit", etc.) it will not render.
- When creating a WebEditButton, if you want to control the icon that displays on the Page Editor, you need to set the Data/Icon through Raw Values.  Otherwise, the value gets saved to Appearance/Icon, which controls the icon for the content item, not the PageEditor button. This is due to a bug with the Content Editor.